# Reorder elements in different containers based on screen size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am looking for a cross-browser way to set different position and display order for elements based on screen size, while maintaining the initial DOM order. The elements are initially in separate containers and standard ways like `float`/`clear` in media queries would probably not suffice.

Also, it would be nice if it was pure CSS solution.

This fiddle uses javascript to manipulate the DOM on load and resize event, which is undesired.

https://jsfiddle.net/168y076w/

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div id="header">HEADER</div>
  <div id="left_column">
    <div id="left_box_1">LEFT BOX 1</div>
    <div id="left_box_2">LEFT BOX 2</div>
  </div>
    <div id="main_content_holder_for_big_devices"></div>
  <div id="right_column">
    <div id="right_box_1">RIGHT BOX 1</div>
    <div id="main_content_holder_for_small_devices">
      <div id="mid_column">MID COLUMN</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right_box_2">RIGHT BOX 2</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
}
#mid_column {
  background: aqua;
  height: 60px;
}
#left_box_1, #left_box_2 {
  background: blue;
  height: 40px;
}
#right_box_1 {
  background: yellow;
  height: 40px;
}
#right_box_2 {
  background: purple;
  height: 40px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    width: 600px;
  }
  #left_column, #mid_column, #right_column {
    float: left;
  }
  #left_box_1, #left_box_2, #right_box_1, #right_box_2 {
    width: 150px;
  }
  #mid_column {
    width:300px;
    background: aqua;
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
const SMALL_DEVICE_WIDTH = 600;

var $holder_for_small = $( "#main_content_holder_for_small_devices" );
var $holder_for_big = $( "#main_content_holder_for_big_devices" );

window.addEventListener( "resize", move_content_in_dom );
window.addEventListener( "load", move_content_in_dom );

function move_content_in_dom() {
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    if( w < SMALL_DEVICE_WIDTH ) {
    if( $holder_for_big.html() !== "" ) {
      $holder_for_small.html( $holder_for_big.html() );
      $holder_for_big.html( "" );
    }
  } else {
    if( $holder_for_small.html() !== "" ) {
      $holder_for_big.html( $holder_for_small.html() );
      $holder_for_small.html( "" );
    }
  }
}
```

This image illustrates the layout I want to achieve. On small devices like phones, after header on top, I want to have the boxes from left column, after them **I want one box from the right column, after that the main content, and after that another box from the right column**.

[image: Desired layout mockup]

I am hoping for an answer that would give me the right tools so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, what you're trying to do is only possible in pure CSS for Firefox. It's a little complicated, but what you're looking to do, abstractly, is arrange grandchildren elements independently from child elements (items independently from columns). This is possible in Firefox because it has implemented `display: contents`, which allows child elements to become "invisible" to their parents, giving you CSS control over the order of grandchildren elements. Here's what I mean:

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  margin-bottom: 5vh;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.flex-container .cell {
  padding: 4vmin;
}
.flex-container .flex-header {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
.flex-container .flex-sideNav {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}
.flex-container .flex-mainContainer {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 2;
}
.flex-container .flex-mainContainer div {
  background-color: aqua;
}
.flex-container .flex-rightColumn {
  flex: 1;
}
.flex-container .flex-toolbar {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.flex-container .flex-adContainer {
  background-color: purple;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .flex-container > div {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1 0;
  }
  .flex-container .flex-header {
    order: 1;
  }
  .flex-container .flex-sideNav {
    order: 2;
  }
  .flex-container .flex-toolbar {
    order: 3;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .flex-container .flex-mainContainer {
    order: 4;
  }
  .flex-container .flex-adContainer {
    order: 5;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .flex-container .flex-rightColumn {
    display: contents;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-container'>
 <div class='flex-header  cell'>
  Header.
 </div>
 <div class='flex-sideNav'>
  <div class='cell'>Sidenav One.</div>
  <div class='cell'>Sidenav, Redux.</div>
 </div>
 <div class='flex-mainContainer'>
  <div class='cell'>Main item, one.</div>
  <div class='cell'>Main item, two.</div>
  <div class='cell'>Main item, three.</div>
 </div>
 <div class='flex-rightColumn'>
  <div class='flex-toolbar  cell'>
   Toolbar.
  </div>
  <div class='flex-adContainer  cell'>
   Ads.
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

(Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/ianm/pen/NNeQWL) for your convenience)... You'll notice on non-Firefox browsers, *Toolbar* can't be separated from *Ads* in pure CSS, but Firefox correctly implements this rule:

```
.flex-container .flex-rightColumn {
    display: contents;
  }
```

And you get what you want. So short answer: Use flexbox and it'll look good today only for Firefox; use JavaScript and it'll work today for everyone. Good luck!

Comment: Actually I think I have just done it using absolute positioning and floating. Tested successfully on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Vivaldi and IE 11 on Windows; Chromium and Firefox on Linux; Chrome and Android browser on Android. Failed on IE8 due to lack of media queries support, so I added styles to a conditional comment which enforces styles for large screens in IE < 9 (nobody using it needs responsivity anyways). http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vGbYeK?editors=0100

Comment: Cool, good job! Worth noting that your question was "Reorder elements in different containers based on screen size", and in your solution, you just put them in the same container ("right_column"), so it might not be exactly what you want when you begin adding content. But, good luck!

Comment: True. The question was originally named "Main content between rows from side column (on small devices only)", and it was so specific that guys made fun of me asking if they shall send me a paypal address, so I simplified it for the cost of reducing unambiguousity.